# How to save one-to-one mapping entity in greendao?

Tags: android, greendao

I have `entityA` and `entityB` that have a one-one relationship between them (`entityA.a = entityB`).

My question is: if I set `entityA.a = entityB`, then insert `entityA`, will `entityB` automatically be inserted?

I think it should be, but it looks like it's not.

Does that mean I should insert `entityB` myself?

By the way, I know I should call `insert` myself for a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't be inserted. A relation is a link between two existing entities, you should first insert both entities and set de relation after.